Modify object property passed as a prop
In my parent component, I have a ref:
const person = ref({ name: 'John Doe', parent: { name: 'Jane Doe' } })

In my child component, I recieve the entire object:
<parent-picker :person="person" />

Is it ok to alter the person's "parent" property inside child-component, or does it fall under the prop modification anti-pattern?

Alter in which way? Please, show what parent-picker does. The solution depends on this. Yes, it's an antipattern.

@EstusFlask assign a different object to the property or set it to null.

To replace person obect completely, use modelValue and update:modelValue event, this allows to shorten it to v-model. Otherwise use custom event, it's what the answer shows

No, it's generally considered an anti-pattern to directly modify a prop in the child component. Instead, you should emit an event to inform the parent component of the change.
Child component
this.person.parent.name = 'New Name'; // ❌ This is considered an anti-pattern!

this.$emit('update-parent', this.localParentName); // ✅ Correct approach: Emit the updated value

Parent component
<parent-picker :person="person" @update-parent="updateParent" />

updateParent(newName) {
  person.value.parent.name = newName; // ✅ Properly update the nested property
}

